# How to create a directory under /var/run directory?

Tags: linux, directory, volatile

I am trying to create a directory called "program" under the directory `/var/run/`. Finally I want this `/var/run/program`.

For this I have created a configuration file under

```
/etc/default/volatiles
[/etc/default/volatiles]# cat 99_program
d root root 0755 /run/program none
[/etc/default/volatiles]#
```

And then I rebooted my hardware.
But, this is not creating the directory. I am not sure who executes this configuration file. I found in the internet either `systemd-tmpfiles` or `populate-volatiles.sh` takes of creating of volatile directories.
I am unable to find these 2 scripts only my hardware.

I have also tried with
`d root root 0755 /var/run/program none`
But its not working.

I tried modifying the existing files like `/etc/default/volatile/99-network to include my changes. But it didn't work.

Can somebody tell me if I am missing something? or where did I go wrong?

-Sowmya

Comment: `For this I have created a configuration file under

/etc/default/volatiles` ? Why? Why in that directory?? `populate-volatiles.sh` So is your system running `systemd`? What is your system? What is your distribution?

Answer (score 3):

> Can somebody tell me if I am missing something?

**If** your system is running systemd, then read [man systemd-tmpfiles](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service.html) and then read [man tmpfiles.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html) which is rather clear:

```
SYNOPSIS
       /etc/tmpfiles.d/*.conf
       /run/tmpfiles.d/*.conf
       /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/*.conf
       ~/.config/user-tmpfiles.d/*.conf
       $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/user-tmpfiles.d/*.conf
       ~/.local/share/user-tmpfiles.d/*.conf
       ...
       /usr/share/user-tmpfiles.d/*.conf
```

For example create the file `something.conf` in `/etc/tmpfiles.d/`:

```
d /var/run/program 0755 root root - -
```

Then restart your pc or just issue:

```
$ systemd-tmpfiles  --create
```

and you directory should be created.